# Is there a way to embed windows save dialog

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

The subject has it all. I want to have the Windows save as dialog as part of my own dialog. Is that even possible ?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that what you actually want to do is to extend Windows File Save dialog as opposed to embedding it inside your own. Here are some links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646951%28VS.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646960%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've found this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996463.aspx) from 2005:

> **Extend the Common Dialog Boxes Using Windows Forms 1.x**
>
> Applies to:
> Microsoft® .NET Framework 1.1
> Microsoft® Visual Studio .NET 2003

So I don't know whether it'll be applicable in your case. It might have some pointers though.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass the standard Windows Save As Dialog Box and add your own functionality to it..there's a similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429266/customizing-win32s-save-file-dialog).

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.