# Customized Windows Save Dialog is no Longer Fancy -- Why?

Tags: c++, winapi, customization, savefiledialog, ofnhookproc

In accordance with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429266/customizing-win32s-save-file-dialog) I am customizing a Win32 Save File dialog with a custom template description. Now I have a problem where the Save File dialog doesn't show the left-hand bar with my computer, recent places, etc. I can confirm that removing the custom template brings the left-hand sidebar back. What am I doing that warrants its removal? How do I get both?

**Update:** Here's some of the code I have:

```
info.hInstance = MyGetModuleInstanceRoutine();
info.lpfnHook = MyOFNHookProcRoutine;
info.lpTemplateName = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(myCustomResourceID);
info.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_NOREADONLYRETURN |
              OFN_ENABLESIZING | OFN_ENABLEHOOK | OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_ENABLETEMPLATE;

::GetSaveFileNameW(&info);
```

Notes:

- `MyOFNHookProcRoutine` always returns 0.
- I am aware of the extended flag `OFN_EX_NOPLACESBAR` and it is not set (i.e. `FlagsEx` is 0).

Comment: You are battling a mountain of appcompat.  Post your code to a file sharing service so somebody can take a look-see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the answer from [RED SOFT ADAIR-StefanWoe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017178/customized-windows-save-dialog-is-no-longer-fancy-why/2023738#2023738):

Set WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT to a value >= 0x0500.

The size of the OPENFILENAME structure grew for Windows 2000, and the extra space includes the FlagsEx member; apparently Windows assumes the flag `OFN_EX_NOPLACESBAR` if the structure is too small to contain it. Make sure the `lStructSize` member is set correctly too.

Comment: This was my problem; setting the lStructSize to sizeof(OPENFILENAMEW) resolved the issue; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
```

before

```
#include "windows.h"
```

That accidentally solved the same problem for me.